# Disable a Kendo-UI TreeView node

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a TreeView and I want to disable some nodes when they contain in their data a `state_current != null` like the "disable node" button in the [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/api).

my code is :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var treeview = $('#Tree_view').kendoTreeView({
            template: "#= item.name #",
            dataSource: Parcours,
            dataTextField: 'name',
            loadOnDemand: true,
            expand: onExpandedItem
        });
    });

    function onExpandedItem(e) {

        var id_user = @Model.id;

        var item =  $('#Tree_view').data('kendoTreeView').dataItem(e.node)

        var type = item.fields.type;

        if (item.level() > 0) {
            item.id_parcours = item.parentNode().id_parcours;
            if (item.level() == 2) {
                item.id_promo = item.parentNode().id;
            }
        }
        else item.id_parcours = item.Id;

        switch (type) {
            case 'parcours':
                item.children.transport.options.read = {
                    url: '@Url.Action("Get_Session", "Users")' + '?user_id=' + id_user,
                    dataType: "json",
                };
                break;

            case 'session':
                item.children.transport.options.read = {
                    url: '@Url.Action("Get_Matiere")' + '?user_id=' + id_user,
                    dataType: "json"
                };
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    var Matiere = {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '@Url.Action("Get_Matiere")',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json'
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    name: 'Name',
                    type: 'matiere'
                },
                hasChildren: false,
            }
        }
    }

    var Session = {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '@Url.Action("Get_Session")',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json'
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    id: 'IdPromo',
                    name: 'NamePromo',
                    type: 'session',
                    date: 'Date',
                    state: 'State_current',
                },
                hasChildren: true,
                children: Matiere
            }
        }
    }

    var Parcours = {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '@Url.Action("Get_Parcours", "Users")',
                data: {user_id: @Model.id},
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json'
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    id: 'Id',
                    name: 'Name',
                    type: 'parcours'
                },
                hasChildren: true,
                children: Session
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: *When* you want to disable? When the node is clicked; When user click a disable button to disable all nodes at once? This isn't clear yet.

Comment: Node can be disable at the begin, it depend of the variable "State_current" and i want to disable/enable with a button according with "State_current" (State_current = null -> can disable / State_current != null -> can enable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this where you want to disable the nodes

```
var selectedNode = treeview.select();
    treeview.enable(selectedNode, false);
```

Here treeview should be your treeview object, you can select it as below once the treeview is created. And instead of selectedNode you can give the node which you need to disable.

`var treeview = $('#Tree_view').data("kendoTreeView");`

If you want to do this while the treeview renders first you can check this in kendoTreeView databound event, or in select event if you want it while selecting.

Comment: Hi Karthik Sivaraj, thanks for your help, it's work !!

Comment: Happy that it helped you. Cheers :-)